# prove that every generating set of a vector space $V$ has a minimal generating set

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

There are two ways to prove that every $k$-vector space $V$ has a basis. First, choose a linearly independent set of $V$, use Zorn lemma to prove that it must be contained by a maximal linearly independent set, then prove that the maximal linearly independent set is a basis.

Second, we can choose a generating set $B$ of $V$, prove that there is a minimal generating set which is contained in $B$, and then prove that every minimal generating set is a basis. However, I don't know how to prove that every generating set of a vector space has a minimal generating set, could someone help me with that?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An infinite generating set of a finite dimensional vector space contains a basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758882/an-infinite-generating-set-of-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-contains-a-basis). Look at @AsafKaragila's answer in particular.

Comment: Are you assuming that your vector space is finite dimensional?

Comment: You have to be careful; a direct application of a reverse Zorn's lemma need not work. For example, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3078969/intersection-of-totally-ordered-set-of-spanning-sets-is-still-spanning/3079022#3079022).

Comment: In other words: the collection of generating subsets reverse-ordered by inclusion need *not* satisfy Zorn's Lemma. So you cannot hope to prove that every generating set contains a minimal generating set by applying Zorn's Lemma to that collection. The standard method is instead to consider the *linearly independent* subsets of your generating set, and prove that a maximal element of that collection spans and is a minimal spanning set. But that just turns you into the initial method in disguise.

Comment: I am sorry, but I read an answer in that link (the one using Zorn lemma), and seems that it does not use the assumption that the space is finite-dimensional, so I am a little bit confused why it can not work for an arbitrary vector space.

Comment: @cbyh: It does work in general; in fact, the answer explicitly says you do not need to assume that the space is finite dimensional.