# Prove that from a generating family of a finite dimensional vector space we can find a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I would like to show that from a generating family of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ we can always extract a basis.

Here is my attempt

Let $(u_i)_{i=1,...,p}$ be a generating family of $V$. This means that for any vector $v$ of $V$

$v=\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_i u_i,\quad (\lambda_i)_{i=1,...,p}\in\mathbb{K}^{p}$

If this family is not linearly independent, then there exists $\lambda_p \neq 0$ such that

$u_p=-\frac{1}{\lambda_p}\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\lambda_i u_i$

(the choice of the index p can always be done by a change of the order of the vectors of this family which will have no incidence thereafter) which means that $u_p$ is not indispensable in this family to be generative, we end up with the following generative family $(u_i)_{i=1,...,p-1}$ and we reproduce the same procedure until we arrive at an independent family : a generating and independent family and thus a basis of $V$.

Is this seems correct to you ?

Thank you a lot

EDIT : Thank's to Jean-Claude Arbault a big mistake has been removed.

Comment: Basically yes. Note that the generating family may already be a base, i.e. *"Since this family is not linearly independent"* is not correct: **if** it's not linearly independent, then you can remove a vector and continue the process, otherwise you stop before removing any vector.

Comment: You are totally right . Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works as long as the generating set you start with is finite (which is necessary for your labeling of them as $u_1, \dots, u_p$). Keep in mind that even in a finite dimensional vector space, there are infinite generating sets (as long as the base field is infinite): for example the whole vector space is a generating set.

It is still true that any generating set contains a basis, see eg [An infinite generating set of a finite dimensional vector space contains a basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758882/an-infinite-generating-set-of-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-contains-a-basis).